# Unable to redirect to home ("/") in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I am making a web-app using nextjs with redirects in the sidebar. Currently there is two other redirects to "/ex" and "/example", and both works as intended. I also have the "/" redirect, but instead of taking me to "/" it takes me to a 404 page, and rendering the _error.tsx file. This is the Link:

```
<Link
    href={"/"}
>
    <h3>Random Text</h3>
</Link>
```

I am using the app layout, and I am trying to access app/page.tsx

EDIT:
As stated in comments, it worked to delete the .next directory, but I am not sure why.

Comment: Error resolved after deleting the .next dir, and restarting client